# ElasticSearch match multi word keyword tokenized field

Tags: elasticsearch

We have following prerequisites:
Document indexed on ES that has **tags** field is array of strings for example: ['visa', 'credit card']
We want to search these documents on **tags** field.

Requirements:

1. If document has  **tags**: ['visa', 'credit card'], we want to return it only if user has written 'visa' or 'credit card', we do not want to accept 'card', 'credit' and similar partials, so ​composed terms must be in total match.
2. We want to have fuzziness in the search for **tags** field on single and compound terms.
3. We want use synonyms on the **tags** field.

So I implemented:

```
"tags_analyzer": {
  "filter": [
    "lowercase",
    "asciifolding",
    "synonyms_expand",
  ],
  "char_filter": [
    "quotes",
    "html_strip",
    "ampersand",
    "returns"
  ],
  "type": "custom",
  "tokenizer": "keyword"
},

"query_analyzer": {
  "filter": [
    "lowercase",
    "my_asciifolding",
    "shingle"
  ],
  "char_filter": [
    "quotes",
    "html_strip",
    "ampersand",
    "returns"
  ],
  "type": "custom",
  "tokenizer": "standard"
},

"synonyms_expand": {
  "ignore_case": "true",
  "expand": "true",
  "type": "synonym",
  "synonyms": [
    "visa, credit card",
    "maestro, debit card"
  ],
  "tokenizer": "keyword"
},

"shingle": {
  "max_shingle_size": "3",
  "min_shingle_size": "2",
  "output_unigrams": "true",
  "type": "shingle",
  "filler_token": ""
}
```

using tags_analyzer on index time and query_analyzer on query time.
But this solution doesn't work on fuzzy compound terms.
Does anyone have any idea why or have another solution?